# Pass select option value into named url pattern using Django and Jquery

Tags: jquery, django, url, django-templates

I have a dropdown list in my django template:

```
<select name="submit_new" id="submit_new">
    <option value="Stdo">Studio</option>
    <option value="Flm">Film</option>
    <option value="Drctr">Director</option>
</select>
<button type="submit_type" id="submit_new_button">Go</button>
```

I would like to take the value of the selection and pass it into the django named url pattern

```
$("#submit_new_button").click(function() {
    var NewLink = {% url add_record $("#submit_new").val() %}
    window.location.href = NewLink
});
```

Clearly, as written, this does not work.  How can I used the named pattern **{% url add_record VAR %}** in combination with the jquery value **$("#submit_new").val()**?

**edit**:

My url entry for add_record is:

```
url(r'^add_(?P<modelname>\w+)/$', views.generic_change, name = 'add_record')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely a problem with the add_record entry in urls.py but the template needs a little help as well.  Try being explicit with all the arguments for that [url](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#url) entry.  You can switch to more of a short hadn notation later but for now just try this to get things working:

```
url(r'^add_(?P<modelname>\w+)/$', 
    view='your_app.views.generic_change', 
    name='add_record')
```

And then try this in your template:

```
$("#submit_new_button").click(function() {
    var link = '{% url add_record 'NEWVALUESTUB' %}';
    link = link.replace('NEWVALUESTUB', $("#submit_new").val());
    window.location.href = link;
});
```

Comment: I like this idea.  But I still get a TemplateSyntaxError: Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'add_record' with arguments '(u'--NEW--VALUE--',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.  From some other research, I think there may be no solution because of the way Django renders templates.  Would love to be corrected. . .

Comment: updated the answer based question update.  There is definitely a solution.  You just need to solve one problem at a time; first urls.py then the template ;^)

Comment: I still got a TemplateSyntaxError, but when I removed the hyphens, it worked perfectly (even without changing the url pattern).  Thanks!

Comment: One more tweak to remove the hyphens so the answer matches what eventually worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$("#next-button").click(function() {
    var countryid = $('input:radio[name=countries_list]:checked').val();
    var link = "{% url 'selectbank' value=2 %}";
    link = link.replace('2', countryid);
    window.location.href=link;
    });
</script>
```

I was having same issue with radio buttons. Followed the above answer. But I got the NoReverseMatch found error.

I could able to solve it by this method.